# SQL Server Service Broker with Signed Procedure - Permissions Issues

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions, service-broker

We have the Service Broker running with internal activation enabled. The stored procedure is signed. How is this permissions issue occurring? I thought that the signature user takes over when the procedure is called. Why isn't the permissions issue related to the signature user?

> 916:The server principal "{userName}" is not able to access the database "{sisterDatabaseName}" under the current security context. - Line: 1

We have multiple databases on the same server. These databases are grouped in pairs, with the databases occasionally needing to send information back and forth. Typically, this is done simply by fully qualifying the database name when performing select or inserts between databases.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbname.dbo.tablename
```

However, we have a process that would greatly benefit from asynchronous SQL execution.

Enter the Service Broker! We ran the following script:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON database::databasename TO someuser
ALTER DATABASE databasename SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(20) = ''
DECLARE @char CHAR = ''
DECLARE @charI INT = 0
DECLARE @len INT = 20 -- Length of Password
WHILE LEN(@Password) < @len
BEGIN
    SET @charI = ROUND(RAND()*73,0) + 49
    SET @char = CHAR(@charI)
    SET @Password += @char
END

SET @SQL = '
CREATE CERTIFICATE {certName}
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + '''
WITH SUBJECT = ''Certificate to sign Internal Activation Procedure''

CREATE USER {certificateUserName} FROM CERTIFICATE {certName};

GRANT CONNECT TO PullConfirmRequestQueueProcessorUser;

ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[{procedureName}]
BY CERTIFICATE {certName} WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + '''
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Essentially, we are creating a certificate that can only be assigned to this one specific stored procedure. It is fine for now. This is in the testing phase. If we need a more secure solution that can be extended to multiple procedures, we can come up with one later. I am not worried about it. But, I would expect this test to work.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[{procedureName}]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[{procedureName}] AS' 
    GRANT EXECUTE ON {procedureName} TO {username}
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[{procedureName}]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @SSBSTargetDialogHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        DECLARE @RecvdRequestMessage XML;
        DECLARE @RecvdRequestMessageTypeName sysname;
        WHILE (1=1)
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            WAITFOR
            ( RECEIVE TOP(1)
            @SSBSTargetDialogHandle = conversation_handle,
            @RecvdRequestMessage = CONVERT(XML, message_body),
            @RecvdRequestMessageTypeName = message_type_name
            FROM dbo.{queueName}
            ), TIMEOUT 1000;

            IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            BEGIN
                IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                BREAK;
            END

            IF @RecvdRequestMessageTypeName = N'{messageName}'
            BEGIN
                --Statements to process message in this database and "sister" database

                END CONVERSATION @SSBSTargetDialogHandle;
            END
            ELSE IF @RecvdRequestMessageTypeName IN (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog',N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error')
            BEGIN
                END CONVERSATION @SSBSTargetDialogHandle;
            END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO ServiceBrokerErrors(
            MessageXml,
            DialogHandle,
            TimeLoggedUTC,
            ErrorNumber,
            ErrorSeverity,
            ErrorState,
            ErrorProcedure,
            ErrorLine,
            ErrorMessage)
        VALUES(@RecvdRequestMessage,@SSBSTargetDialogHandle,GETUTCDATE(),ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE())
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

The following four queries return the same value:

```
SELECT sid FROM {mainDatabase}.sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'dbo'
SELECT sid FROM {sisterDatabase}.sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'dbo'
SELECT owner_sid FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{mainDatabase}'
SELECT owner_sid FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{sisterDatabase}'
```

Comment: Is that error occurring during activation? Which is to say, messages are successfully arriving in the target queue? I'm not seeing anything that would require exotic permissions (which I would consider module signing to be somewhat exotic). So long as whatever database principal is executing the activation proc (which you can see in `sys.service_queues`) has permission to do everything in its local database, everything should be good.

Comment: @BenThul Correct. The only "exotic" part is the fact that I am trying to update data in two databases from that activation procedure. The activation procedure is fairly short, basically calling a stored procedure that used to be processed synchronously, but updating data across two databases.

Comment: fwiw, 3-part names like dbname.dbo.tablename are **deprecated** and slated for removal.

Comment: You're trying to update data? Where? In the definition of the procedure you have posted above, I only see a `receive` statement happening. Seems like there's a lot hidden behind "--Statements to process message in this database and 'sister' database". It feels like *that's* where the error is happening.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - can you point me to documentation of three- (and, presumably four-) part naming being deprecated? That's news to me.

Comment: @BenThul there is a comment in what I posted:
`--Statements to process message in this database and "sister" database`

That is where processing is actually happening. The error is occurring in the stored procedure this activation procedure calls. That stored procedure is an old block of SQL code written probably 20 years ago. It would take a while if I needed to refactor it. Especially since it is working fine when run outside of the Internal Activation security context.

Comment: @BenThul I was not aware it was deprecated either. So, I just ran this query: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters   
WHERE object_name LIKE '%SQL%Deprecated Features%'
ORDER BY cntr_value DESC` and it shows me I am using a lot of deprecated features.

Comment: @BenThul It's buried, but it's in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I am heading out for the night. I need a break from this, lol. Tomorrow, I will take another crack at looking at this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - yikes. That seems profoundly ignorant of extant workloads on the part of MS.

Comment: @BenThul Eh. We'll see what the follow-through is. Statements with no semi-colon terminator has been deprecated for more than two decades and still works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

For cross-database access, you need to copy the certificate to each database accessed by the signed proc and create a certificate user in order to provide a security context.

Sample script to copy the cert to the other database and create the cert user:

```
USE {mainDatabase};
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('{certName}')
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = certencoded(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           certprivatekey(@cert_id,
              '{password}',
              '{password}');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE {certName}
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1) + ',
          DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''{password}'',
          ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''{password}'')';

EXEC {sisterDatabase}.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
GO

USE {sisterDatabase];
CREATE USER {certificateUserName} FROM CERTIFICATE {certName};
```

Comment: @SlipEternal, that suggests the working environments are different such that cross-database  ownership chaining is enabled in a trustworthy database.  The certificate copy method is more secure.

Comment: Trying this out now :)

Comment: The code ran without error, but I get the same error when trying to use the signed procedure. Does the procedure have to be signed from the sister database? It doesn't even exist in the sister database.

Comment: @SlipEternal, is `db_chaining` enabled in the databases?

Comment: It is off, both in the environment where this fails and in the three environments where it succeeds.

Comment: @SlipEternal, is mainDatabase `TRUSTWORTHY`? That will allow cross database access if the databases have the same owner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255819/discussion-between-slipeternal-and-dan-guzman).